# What is faster: iterating through Python AST to find particular type nodes, or override the visit_type method?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

The `ast` module in Python allows multiple traversal strategies. I want to understand, is there any significant gain in terms of complexity when choosing a specific way of traversal?

Here are two examples:

**Example 1**

```
class GlobalVisitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def generic_visit(self, tree):
            for node in tree.body:
                if isinstance(node, ast.Global):
                   *transform the ast*
```

**Example 2**

```
class GlobalVisitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Global(self, tree):
            *transform the ast*
```

In Example 1, I override the generic_visit method, providing my own implementation of how I want to traverse the tree. This, however, happens through through visiting every node in the body, so O(n).

In Example 2, I override the visit_Global, and I am thus able to do stuff with all Global type nodes immediately. That's how `ast` works.

I want to understand, in Example 2, does `ast` have instant **O(1)** access to the nodes I specify through overriding visit_*field*(self, node), or it just goes through the tree again in **O(n)**, looking for the nodes I need in the background, just simplifying my life a little bit?

Comment: Quickest way to check is look at the relevant [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/ast.py#L412-L420).  You can see this is a recursive method by default that would traverse down the entire input AST, and will invoke your `visit_Global` via the [`visit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/ast.py#L406-L410) method on the matching node.

Comment: Well, iterating over `tree.body` is completely wrong - `tree.body` isn't a collection of every node in an AST. It's an attribute of `Module` nodes that gives a list of the nodes for top-level statements in the module. You'll miss every `global` statement that matters (since barring extremely weird `exec` cases, a correct `global` statement is never top-level), and you'll crash on non-`Module` node input.

Comment: @metatoaster thank you! As ASTs grow larger, it seems that this would result in terrible complexity. Do you know whether there are libraries, or other ways, that would allow faster access? Or should this rather be interpreted as an AI Search problem, and I should just aim to override generic_visit in a way that would imply implementing an effective search algorithm, e.g. A*? I just don't understand how can we deal with extremely large ASTs if it requires the exploration of the entire search space each time...

Comment: It's hard to consider linear time "terrible complexity", and A* wouldn't make any sense for this task. If you want something faster, pruning would make more sense - most nodes cannot have a `global` statement in the subtree rooted at that node (since most nodes are expressions), but the visitor is still going to traverse those trees by default.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, my bad. I was saying that in the context of performing alterations to the AST within the context of a problem I'm working on, where it requires other loops that make the complexity worse. Btw, I'm willing to validate your comment if you format it as an answer!

Comment: @JJKam: I think you should focus on getting the code right before you think about maximizing speed. Your first example does not look right to me: unless you only want to look at top-level children (and in that case, why would you use a NodeTransformer?). Unless you're trying to modify nodes, you should use NodeVisitor, not NodeTransformer. If you don't want the services NodeVisitor (or NodeTransformer) provides (which is basically to allow you to use named methods to simplify your code), just recursively iterate using ast.iter_child_nodes. If you have a specific question, ask it instead.

Comment: @rici I do want to modify the ast, that's why I use NodeTransformer. I modified the question to make it clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some takeaways from the comments provided by @metatoaster, @user2357112 and @rici :

**1.** Example 1 is completely wrong. One should not aim to traverse the tree in the way that was described, because iterating over `tree.body` is completely wrong - `tree.body` isn't a collection of every node in an AST. It's an attribute of `Module` nodes that gives a list of the nodes for top-level statements in the module. It will miss every `global` statement that matters (since barring extremely weird `exec` cases, a correct `global` statement is never top-level), it will crash on non-Module node input..

If you want to implement a correct version of Example 1, just recursively iterate using ast.iter_child_nodes. However, note that iter_child_nodes is correctly named. It is not iter_descendant_nodes. It does not visit anything other than direct children. The recursive walk must be implemented in the action performed on each child.

**2.** When implemented correctly, two approached are equivalent, and imply a recursive traversal, however overriding a visit_*type*(self, node) saves you some time. **No gain in terms of complexity will be achieved.**

**3.** Only use NodeTransformer if you want to alter the AST, otherwise just use NodeVisitor.

**Finally**, `ast` doesn't seem to be documented exhaustively enough, refer to [this](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tofrom.html) for a more detailed documentation. It is a bit outdated (by ~ a year), but explains some fundamentals better than the original `ast`.